# RegisterHotKey() causes error 1459 (This operation requires an interactive window station) in a service

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I've read several similar threads on SO that discuss starting another process and registering a hot key in that child process, but my situation is slightly different.

I'm building a Windows service that performs many varied functions, and would like to keep it as a service since I need my code to run on system start up, before user login and continually until system shutdown.

I've also invested **a lot** of effort into getting the rest of it to work already, so having to rebuild the whole project as a console app and then figure out how to run that on system start up would be far from ideal.

Here is the thread callback that does the bulk of the **actual** work. I've verified that everything runs fine up to this point, but I get 1459 from `GetLastError` after the `RegisterHotKey` call:

```
DWORD WINAPI SvcWorkerThread(LPVOID param) {
    // Register a hot key to perform an internet search of the selected text
    // in the focused application, whenever the user presses Ctrl+Alt+S.
    if (!RegisterHotKey(nullptr, 1, MOD_CONTROL | MOD_ALT | MOD_NOREPEAT, 0x53)) {
        // LogError() calls GetLastError() and FormatMessage() to get the system-defined error
        // message from the last unsuccessful API call, and logs it to a file. The parameter is
        // the name of the function that failed.
        return LogError("RegisterHotKey");
    }

    // Repeatedly poll our stop event and process any WM_HOTKEY
    // messages that are sent to this thread while its running.
    MSG msg;
    while (WaitForSingleObject(svcStopEvent, 0) != WAIT_OBJECT_0) {
        if ((PeekMessage(&msg, nullptr, WM_HOTKEY, WM_HOTKEY, PM_REMOVE)) != 0) {
            // LogMessage() is basically the same as LogError(), but
            // doesn't bother with the whole error collecting process.
            LogMessage("User action", "Pressed hot key Ctrl+Alt+S");
        }
    }

    // Service has been stopped; allow thread to exit normally.
    return ERROR_SUCCESS;
}
```

Is there absolutely no way around this error, apart from starting another process? MTIA :-)

Comment: Calling this in a service does not make any sense, it can't detect any keystrokes.  Google "session 0 isolation" to learn more.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant, will do! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code that interacts with an interactive desktop will need to run in that interactive desktop. Your service runs in isolation in session 0.

You will have to separate out those parts of the system that are interactive and run them in an interactive process. You can retain the service to manage these interactive processes, and communicate using IPC.

Comment: Thanks mate, sounds like a good workaround for now. Will accept your answer in a day or two if nothing better comes along :-)

Comment: It's not going to be a "workaround for now", it's the only way to do it.

Comment: I **have** since found another way to do it, but it's a little hacky and potentially very dangerous...so thanks again for the answer :-)

Comment: I can't imagine that you are actually interacting with the interactive session from your service.

Comment: No; you made me realise that it is perfectly fine to start an interactive process from the service which will, in turn, handle everything else. I really didn't want to have to rewrite the code to fit this design, but it actually wasn't as difficult as I expected. Plus you and @HansPassant made me realise that I have no choice, hence the thank yous and acceptance of this answer :-)